# Question list says "Votes" instead of "Score", but it displays score, not votes

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, profile-page, typographical-error

[image: Vote counter]

I think it is pretty self-explanatory how it is right now, but it seems somewhat weird to see '-1 votes'.
Might someone new to SE think that this is a total vote counter and think the '-1' is a bug?

Should this be changed to "score", "usefulness", "rating" or something on that line?

Comment: It's trying to say "score". I don't know how they managed to misspell "score" as "votes", but... they did. It's one of the *many* regressions in the recent redesign of the profile page. One of the less infuriating ones in day-to-day usage, but, nevertheless, very bad design for the reasons you mentioned: it leads to confusion. (It certainly shouldn't be changed to "punctuation"—that's not what [punctuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuation) means!)

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know that. Sorry about the punctuation thing, I am Spanish and in Spanish, score and [puntuación](https://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/puntuaci%C3%B3n.html) is kind of the same! I had 'score' in my mind but I couldn't remember the word haha

Comment: Maybe it's trying to tell the future, and I can retract my vote before I make it in the future,  Then there would be -1 "votes". :)

Comment: Yeah "score" although I understand why they wouldn't use a term like that, it's too gamey. You also don't say "my question has 30 points!". It's a vote tally, basically.

Comment: Although @Gimby, 'score' already shows if you hover over the 'Hot', 'Week' and 'Month' filters in the questions list. Rating could be a viable alternative.

Comment: It's a long-standing bug where "score" was called "votes". This has now been updated to "score" in several places but not everywhere yet.

Comment: To support VLAZ's comment, [here's one on Feb 2022 by SE staff mentioning the change from "votes" to "score" in passing about "answer sorting"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376062/revisiting-changes-to-answer-sorting-menu-better-use-of-space-moving-menu-into)

Comment: However, [another post by SE staff also on Feb 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375806/241919) mention: "*Our main goal was to switch to "Score" where it made sense: The layout doesn't display the word "Score" as a unit. (e.g.: "15 score" as opposed to "15 votes" just seem weird to us right now) [...] Unfortunately these restrictions mean that **question listings all around the website will remain unchanged for now**. We are working to find better wording for "Score" that can also be used as a unit (e.g.: "points"), and on a plan to implement those with minimum negative impact to you.*"

Comment: They could put Score: Number, and then they would not need to look for a unit. Although I understand their point. (no pun intented)

Comment: "*They could put Score: Number, and then they would not need to look for a unit.*" that was brought up pretty fast. The main problem is that they overhauled the UI and *then* decided to finally change over to Score. Which didn't work with the overhaul. Would have been easier if the Score thing was taken into consideration first and then the UI was changed according to what it actually should have been.

Comment: @S.Dre fair point. Ugh, if I would have to pick one thing to hate it'd be inconsistency.